# Pre subscript versus tensor

Tags: subscripts, tensor

What is the best way to typeset `\sqcup` with two subscripts left/right.

For sure, **1st** and **2nd** are wrong. But they help us to see the baseline for the indexes.

The **3rd** and **4th** look equal except by the space around. Also, they insert the index too low (I think).

The **5th** produces almost the same but change the baseline for indexes. However it gives me an error (since `\sqcup` is not an operator).

> Limit controls must follow a math operator. `$A \sideset{_f}{_g}{\sqcup}`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

$A_g  \sqcup_f B$

$A{}_g\sqcup_f B$

$A\prescript{}{g}{\sqcup}_fB$

$A\tensor[_g]{\sqcup}{_f}B$

% $A\sideset{_g}{_f}{\sqcup} B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As explained in `amsmath` documentation, `\sideset` is meant for big operators.

Comment: @egreg, OK. I just inserted to show the good positioning of indexes. Its spacing looks better than the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define the symbol as `\mathbin`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dsqcup}[2]{% #1 presubscript, #2 postsubscript
  \mathbin{_{#1}\sqcup_{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

$A\dsqcup{f}{f}B$

$A\dsqcup{g}{f}B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: Is `\sqcup` a mathbin char? If yes, it inserts space before/after it, isn't? In this case, are the spaces between the indexes and `\sqcup` the right ones?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, it is: `\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqcup}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"74}`